# Why cant i import @RestController spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P39NT.png)i'm just trying to set up a simple spring boot application that has rest controller. But cant import Rest Controller. Here is my main method

```
package com.test.demo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And here is my build.gradle.  the script collects all the jars on the classpath and builds a single jar.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.2.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot-docker'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

Any Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Whats the error? Compilation error? By the way normally you dont usr 'RestController' in the SpringBoot app main class. Define a new class (ie MyRestController) which will define your endpoints

Comment: If i add in an endpoint the error is "error: cannot find symbol
 @RequestMapping("/")"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I invalidated and restarted the caches which worked!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing import for `@RequestMapping("/")`.

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
```

Comment: Yeah no, still getting red highlight over the web part of the import. I added in a screen shot in the description. Am i not missing a dependency?

Comment: these are part of dependency `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web`.. make sure your project is compiled and have these dependencies.

Comment: Sorry, yes it is. I  invalidated and restarted the caches which worked! Thanks for the help!

Comment: in my case, I have the correct dependencies, but the silly me thought naming the class "RestController" would just be fine, apparently it doesn't and had to rename it to something new for it to properly initialize this class as an actual controller. haha.